# Using Interpolation in Matlab to return a function

Tags: matlab

I've got a silly problem, I'm looking to take a few data points, fit a polynomial function through it and then differentiate that function to get that particular functions optimal point. As such I have done some reading online and I've used the Matlab 'spline' function. Here is some code:

```
a = [50; 100; 150;200;250;300;350]
b = [56;23;22;18;14;15;21]
y = spline(a,b)
```

But when I used `diff(y)` I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> diff
Function 'diff' is not supported for class 'struct'.
```

I'm not too familiar with Matlab, so any help would really be appreciated

Comment: I believe you should first fit a polynomial using [polyfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) function and then you get a symbolic function. Use [symbolic differentiation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html) afterwards to get the functions optimal point.

Comment: In addition to Parag's comment: `spline` does not return a function, but a `struct` that contains the the spline information (e.g. coefficients, etc.). That's why `diff` cannot deal with it.

Comment: Of course, since a polynomial in matlab is represented as a vector of coefficients, you can get the derivative of an Nth order polynomial p by pd=p(1:end-1).*[N-1:-1:1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments:

```
y = polyfit(a,b,2)
syms x
g = y(1)*x^2 + y(2)*x + y(3)
diff(g)
```

and you get the derivative of the function g. Much thanks to the guys in the comment section!

Comment: Great! You figured it out yourself.